# Why is Code runner renaming my file to "tempCodeRunnerFile.java"? (causing "error: class X is public, should be declared in a file named X.java")

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, error-handling, compilation, vscode-code-runner

I have some problems with Visual Studio Code. I am using the Code Runner extension and Java for Multithreading and Multiprocessing training... but VS Code won't run my code.

Important: The name of the file is **Main.java** , the same of the **public class Main**

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        PrintThread t = new PrintThread("thread1");
        t.start();
    }
}

class PrintThread extends Thread {
    private int sleepTime;

    public PrintThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        sleepTime = (int) (Math.random() * 5001);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.err.println(getName() + " going to sleep for " + sleepTime + ".");
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.err.println(getName() + " done sleeping.");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> ```
> tempCodeRunnerFile.java:5: error: class Main is public, should be
> declared in a file named Main.java public class Main{
>        ^ 1 error
> ```

I tried to change different names of file and public class (same name) but it doesn't work...

Comment: Looks like the name of the file is not Main.java. With uppercase M.

Comment: looks more like it is `tempCodeRunnerFile.java` from the error message `tempCodeRunnerFile.java:5: error: class Main is public, ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid tempCodeRunnerFile.go appear in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097653/how-to-avoid-tempcoderunnerfile-go-appear-in-the-project)

Comment: I disagree with [the proposed dup target](/q/63097653). I've edited the question to be more clear about what the problem is, and you can see my answer, which should also indicate that the proposed dup target is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're running a selected code snippet. If you want to do that with the Code Runner extension, you'll need to adjust the `code-runner.temporaryFileName` setting to the name of your main class.

The setting's description:

> Temporary file name used in running selected code snippet. When it is set as empty, the file name will be random.

Try editing your [workspace `.vscode/settings.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) to include the following:

```json
"code-runner.temporaryFileName": "Main"
```

See also [the configuration docs for the Code Runner extension](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration).

If you don't want to run the selected snippet, then make sure you don't have any selected text when invoking Code Runner- either that, or put `"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true` in your settings.json.